# Will two privately tagged types of a public subprogram's profile require it to be packaged?

Tags: oop, ada

Package `P` below has two private types declared in it, immediately followed by a subprogram taking a parameter of either type. Both types are tagged, but privately tagged only. Still, the compiler complains that `Proc` can only be dispatching in one type. So, `private` does not “hide” the tag, and presumably, `Proc` will be interpreted as a primitive operation of two tagged type candidates? Maybe that's because the body will in the end take the actual tagged objects. On the other hand, `'Class` cannot be added to the parameter profile.

When trying to work around the issue in as simple as possible a way, I could only think of a nested package, fencing one of the types out, or making `Proc` non-primitive in it. In increasing order of visual disturbance, then, the latter

```
package P is

    type T1 is private;
    type T2 is private;

    procedure Proc (A : T1; B : out T2);  -- !

    package Not_Dispatching is
        procedure Proc (A : T1; B : out T2);
    end Not_Dispatching;

private
    type T1 is tagged null record;
    type T2 is tagged null record;
end P;
```

and the former:

```
package PP is

    type T1 is private;
    package Exclude_From_Dispatching is
        type T2 is private;
    private
        type T2 is tagged null record;
    end Exclude_From_Dispatching;
    use Exclude_From_Dispatching;

    procedure Proc (A : T1; B : out T2);

private
    type T1 is tagged null record;
end PP;
```

The ugliness seems to suggest total restructuring. Is there some other, simpler way?

Comment: Any reason for not using `"tagged private"` in the public type declaration? It makes it visible that you're using tagged types, but it would allow `'class` in the subprogram's parameter profile.

Comment: It seems that the reasons for adding tags at all are not strictly OOP ones, namely memory management via `Controlled` and objects conveniently being aliased for `'Access`. So, arguably no reason relates to the types per se, in the public part sense. OTOH, then, maybe another private indirection will do in this case, moving `Controlled` to a component and dropping `new Controlled` from one type's full definition.

Comment: And making one type `tagged private` might actually produce a better design, if a type made for derivation asks the programmer to not make so many private assumptions at the root. Thanks for that, @BrianDrummond!

Comment: Right, making either type `tagged private` solves the immediate problem. Fundamentally, there's nothing to stop both being `tagged private`. But if the design dictates that one type is extensible through derivation and the other isn't, then making one `tagged private` makes that clear up front.